# How does Stack Overflow's SSO model work?

Tags: cross-domain, single-sign-on

Just curious how Stack Overflow uses single sign on across domains. I believe this is something with Apache most likely since cookies fail cross domain. Here's a great example of it in action if you don't know what I'm dribbling on about.

1. Click your username all the way at the top of the page
2. Scroll to the bottom of the page, and click another "account"
   other than Stack Overflow (e.g. SuperUser)

If you look, you are still logged in as a user. Particularly you.

This kind of is an interesting thing, we can vote out the fact that
Stack passes cookies, since they invalidate cross domain, which begs
the question of what exactly they do to keep you logged in cross domain? 
Is it the image trick (I've heard of using gifs to relay information) 
does it have something to do with OpenID or something else entirely.

I know that there are multiple SSO solutions such as JOSSO, OpenSSO, 
CAS, Shibboleth and many others. I do appreciate the seamless nature
Stack Overflow has and just curious if anyone knows their implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do not share credential information. You have to logon separately on each site. If you log out of superuser, you will still be logged in stackoverflow.

Check out your cookies, you have one called `usr` for each domain.

Comment: So what you are implying possibly is that after you log into one site, a controller dispatches logged in info to the other sites which generate separate cookies for each domain? I'm wondering if the SSO is only for OpenID sign ons? I need to test it real quick

Comment: Absolutely not. Logout of all your accounts (SO, SU, etc.). Then log in back into SO, you won't be logged into SU.

Comment: I see what you mean, I was originally under the impression that it was using SSO, but instead it looks like they use no-expire cookies.

Comment: Yep. No-expire cookies make you "feel" like SSO since you never logout of their system. Why would you! ;-)

Comment: Good point. The reason that I brought this up in the first place is we control 2000~ dns' on a single ip (Drupal 7 and Domain Access), and would like to keep our Staff logged in permanently across all sites indefinitely. Maybe I can tweak some settings to allow authorized users of a certain permission level to stay signed on this way?

Comment: If I understand well, you mean that you have 2000 domain (not DNS) assigned to the same IP address. You have a (single?) Drupal 7 that is the CMS to manage all those websites, and what you would like is that the administrators don't have to log again and again to manage those websites. As I'm not a Drupal expert, I would recommend asking another question on SO with those information!

Comment: Yeah that's about right, so we have 2000 domain names pointed at a single IP. Drupal inherently has the ability to use multisite, but for our particular Drupal 7 install we use a module named Domain Access to delegate sites. The gist is though that Domain Access will not allow cross site logins, but yeah, we would like our editors to log in once, and have access to all sites. I tried asking a while ago, but was downvoted multiple times. I'm not sure how to phrase it to get good, valid answers...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe back in 2011 stackexchange didn't have this feature, but now it does exist.
If you log into `stackoverflow.com` and then go to `serverfault.com` and click on '`log in`' you will be automatically logged in (given that you are a member of both `stackoverflow.com` and `serverfault.com`).

This is achieved with Ajax, server-side encryption and timestamping. So no magic whatsoever.

There is a special domain `stackauth.com` that keeps track of stackexchange SSO with Ajax requests like:
https://stackauth.com/auth/global/read?request=8mxxNKQLxiYWd01AQO7D24eF9YSzd62Q5MyLlZhLmdzh0qGz6sOVlJAyC3oj%2B5b4PeVEH8J4x51g0oyiKi2FMQ%3D%3D&nonce=YZRsUwAAAAAMvr%2F34zkmOA%3D%3D